# Running the PowerShell Script from the c#

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line

I am trying to call PowerShell ISE Script from the C#.

I have command that I am running it on the PowerShell

```
. .\Commands.ps1; Set-Product -bProduct 'Reg' -IPPoint 'ServerAddress' -Location  'testlocation' -Terminal 3
```

Now I am trying to create the Command with the c# I have wrote some code Like this.

```
//Set Execution Policy to un restrict
            powershell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
            powershell.AddArgument("unrestricted");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();

        

powershell.AddScript("K:\\Auto\\Cases\\Location\\Commands.ps1", false);
            powershell.AddArgument("Set-Product").AddParameter("bProduct ", "Reg").
                AddParameter("IPPoint", "ServerAddress").
                AddParameter("Location", "testlocation").AddParameter("Terminal", 3);

            powershell.Invoke();
```

I can see its running fine. But its not updating values in my xml file. It suppose to update my values in file. When I try to run it with powershell It does run and works file. But c# code does not work.

Any hint or clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mind the semicolon, so this is basically two statements:

1.) [Dot-sourcing](http://%5Ehttps://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#dot-sourcing-operator-) the script `Commands.ps1`

```
. .\Commands.ps1
```

2.) Invoking the cmdlet `Set-Product`

```
Set-Product -bProduct 'Reg' -IPPoint 'ServerAddress' -Location  'testlocation' -Terminal 3
```

So, you have to treat them as such. Also, `AddScript` expects code, not a file name.

```
powershell
    // dot-source the script
    .AddScript(@". 'K:\Auto\Cases\Location\Commands.ps1'")

    // this is the semicolon = add another statement
    .AddStatement()

    // add the cmdlet
    .AddCommand("Set-Product")
    .AddParameter("bProduct", "Reg")
    .AddParameter("IPPoint", "ServerAddress")
    .AddParameter("Location", "testlocation")
    .AddParameter("Terminal", 3)

    // invoke all statements
    .Invoke();
```

*(Alternatively to `AddStatement()` you can of course split this up in two calls and call `Invoke()` twice.)*

Comment: So. it just need . there and it will work fine ?

Comment: Thanks that works `AddScript(@". K:\Auto\Cases\Location\Commands.ps1")`